# Regex or clause does not match as I want it to

Tags: regex

The regex:

```
jfr [ a-z ]+-((,?)|([ a-z ]+))
```

does not match my string `jfr abra-kadabra`, although it matches `jfr abra-,` (which it should). Why?

Comment: `|` mean alternation match, so your `(,?)` matches ( empty values too ) it doesn't check for `([ a-z ]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not make `,` optional by using `,?`, otherwise grouped expression will also match (and capture) an empty string:

```
jfr [ a-z]+-(,|[ a-z]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f6yUCY/2)

You also have spaces twice in character class which is unnecessary.

However it is recommended to use word boundaries in your regex to avoid matching unwanted extra characters:

```
\bjfr [ a-z]+-(?:,|[ a-z]+\b)
```